# What the best way to compare indexes of an array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, web-applications

I'm trying to compare indexes of an array. However I'm not to sure I'm going about it correctly.  My thoughts are:

```
let tempArray = [tempInfo1,tempInfo2];

if(tempArray[0] == tempArray[1]){
    console.log('true');
}else{
    console.log('false');
}
```

Am I headed in the right direction? Or is this completely off?

Essentially - I'm trying to make a 'matching game'.  Clicking an element stores that element in a tempArray (tempInfo1), and clicking on a second element stores a second value in that array (tempInfo2).  Then I'm trying to check if the values are the same - do something. If not do something else. Does this help?

Comment: Use `===`, not `==`.

Comment: This seems very counter intuitive, you should use objects or map instead

Comment: `Am I headed in the right direction?`  Unsure what you asking, so it's hard to say.

Comment: Actually, you're comparing 2 values, not their indexes

Comment: You are not comparing indexed, you are comparing values, and by definition indexes of the same array must be different.

Comment: do you like to compare each value and check if all values are the same?

Comment: I'm trying to compare two values that are being stored in the same array - I take it thats a bad way to do it? Would it be better to split the array into two - and then compare those?

Comment: it is just an overhead instead of comparing the two values directly. **but** if you need to collect the values first, then it makes sense and all is fine.

Comment: It might be better if you try to explain what problem your trying to solve, often example input & expected output come in very handy here.

Comment: I add some more info on what I'm trying to accomplish. I hope it makes it more clear!

Answer (score 1):

To head you in the right direction

You are probably working with a 4x4 of elements.

Lets say an element looks like this

**HTML**

`<div id="card" value="cat"></div>`

**JavaScript**

```
let lastSelected = null;
document.getElementById('card', (event) => {
    if(event.target.value === lastSelected.value){
      // remove both elements
    } else {
      lastSelected = event.target
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First as mentioned in comments you are comparing values. Indexes are just 0, 1, 2, 3, 4... If you know what resides in an index that might be an option.

and actually that can fail if you're comparing object (and arrays that are a special type of object.)

Imagine this:

```
  var arrayOfDifferentTypes = [
  {
    somekey: "value"
  },
  {
    somekey: "value"
  },
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  "data",
  "data",
  18,
  18
];

console.log(arrayOfDifferentTypes[0] === arrayOfDifferentTypes[1]); // false
console.log(arrayOfDifferentTypes[2] === arrayOfDifferentTypes[3]); // false
console.log(arrayOfDifferentTypes[4] === arrayOfDifferentTypes[5]); // true
console.log(arrayOfDifferentTypes[6] === arrayOfDifferentTypes[7]); // true
```

As you can see it will fail.
You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript) for that kind of comparison.

Comment: hmmm ok.  I think I'm going to have to take a different direction. Thank you kindly for the input!

Answer (score 0):

You are not comparing indices of the array and as per your description that you are trying to make matching game which matches first two values in array then 
**YES** you're headed in right direction but use **===** instead of **==** to compare the values.